# GitLab CI/CD Pipeline with Docker-Compose and AWS ECR Deployment Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, cicd, amazon-ecr

I am attempting to set up a GitLab CI/CD pipeline to build and deploy a Python application and Weaviate database to AWS using Docker Compose. However, I am encountering issues during the pipeline execution.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:23.0.1-dind
      alias: docker
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py3-pip
    - pip install awscli
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}
    - aws --version
    - docker info
    - docker --version
    - docker-compose --version
  script:
    - echo "IMAGE_APP_TAG=${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${APP_NAME}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" >> .env
    - echo "COLLECTION_NAME=${COLLECTION_NAME}" >> .env
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${APP_NAME}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
  only:
    - create-ci-cd-pipeline

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo ${REPOSITORY_URL}:${IMAGE_TAG}
    - TASK_DEFINITION=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition "${TASK_DEFINITION_NAME}" --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}")
    - NEW_CONTAINER_DEFINITION=$(echo $TASK_DEFINITION | jq --arg IMAGE "${REPOSITORY_URL}:${IMAGE_TAG}" '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].image = $IMAGE | .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0]')
    - echo "Registering new container definition..."
    - NEW_TASK_DEFINITION=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}" --family "${TASK_DEFINITION_NAME}" --container-definitions "${NEW_CONTAINER_DEFINITION}")
    - echo "Updating the service..."
    - aws ecs update-service --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}" --cluster "${CLUSTER_NAME}" --service "${SERVICE_NAME}"  --task-definition $(echo $NEW_TASK_DEFINITION | jq -r '.taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn')
  only:
    - web
```

The Python application and the Weaviate database are defined as services in the Docker Compose file.

The pipeline fails at this step:

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
```

With this error message:

```
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth": dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

I am looking for guidance on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is an [gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4794) already 3 years old. But you may get some new insights.

Comment: Does this helps you to resolve the issue? https://serverfault.com/questions/1052496/docker-login-to-aws-ecr-from-gitlab-ci-fails-with-dial-tcp-lookup-docker-on-x

Comment: Hey all, thanks for sharing these issues. Unfortunately this did not help. But I have a docker-socket as GitLab runner which changes maybe some things in the ci yml. But I am still investigation